# VBA - Subtracting varying amount of dates

Tags: vba, excel

I am having trouble figuring out how to subtract the very end date of a contract with the beginning date. However, I cannot figure out how to reference the initial date.[image: Example].

For example, `=D2 - C2` as well as be able to do `=D10 - C5`.  This is what I currently have, and it does not work at all.

```
Dim sla As Long, slacnt As Long, drng As Long, i As Long
i = 2

With Worksheets("Raw")
    slacnt = .Cells(.rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    For sla = i To slacnt
        drng = Sheets("Data").Range("B" & i).Value
        If .Range("B" & i) <> .Range("B" & i).Offset(1, 0) Then
        Else: drng = .Range("D" & i).Value - .Range("C" & i).Value
        End If
    Next sla
End With
```

[image: Image 2]

Any direction would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: For each contract, are the start and end dates always in ascending order?

Comment: Do you have to use VBA for this?  Are you trying to find out the duration (SLA End - SLA Start) from the very last end date for each document?

Comment: Yes, they are always in ascending order.  And yes, I would like to use VBA because I will be doing this calculations of thousands of data.

Comment: Am I right understand that `SLA Start` date is always in the row with `SLA` = 10, and `SLA End` is always in the row preceding to the next row with `SLA` = 10 (or empty row in case of last record)?

Comment: @omegastripes No, you can ignore `Column B`, the two that are more important is `Columns A, C, and D`

Comment: @ACohen please share the expected output, fill the cells manually as you want it to be, and share the screenshot

Comment: @omegastripes I added the photo in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a perfect problem to be resolved with a dictionary, but somehow I am too lazy to do it this way.

However, let's imagine that all the dates are actually numbers (and in Excel they are!) then your input can be translated to something like this:

[image]

What is wanted now is to get the smallest value for each value in column A in column D and the biggest in column E. I have achieved the following:

[image]

This is how the code looks like:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim lngLastRow          As Long
    Dim rngCell             As Range
    Dim rngRange            As Range
    Dim lngMin              As Long
    Dim lngMax              As Long
    Dim lngPreviousRow      As Long
    Dim ws                  As Worksheet

    lngLastRow = lastRow(column_to_check:=2)

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rngRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lngLastRow, 1))

    For Each rngCell In rngRange

        If Len(rngCell) > 0 Then
            If lngPreviousRow > 0 And (rngCell.Row - 1 <> lngPreviousRow) Then
                ws.Cells(lngPreviousRow, 4) = lngMin
                ws.Cells(lngPreviousRow, 5) = lngMax
            End If

            If (rngCell.Row = 1) Or lngPreviousRow = (rngCell.Row - 1) Then
                ws.Cells(rngCell.Row, 4) = WorksheetFunction.Min(rngCell.Offset(0, 1), rngCell.Offset(0, 2))
                ws.Cells(rngCell.Row, 5) = WorksheetFunction.Max(rngCell.Offset(0, 1), rngCell.Offset(0, 2))
            End If

            lngPreviousRow = rngCell.Row
            lngMin = WorksheetFunction.Min(rngCell.Offset(0, 1), rngCell.Offset(0, 2))
            lngMax = WorksheetFunction.Max(rngCell.Offset(0, 1), rngCell.Offset(0, 2))

        Else
            lngMin = WorksheetFunction.Min(lngMin, rngCell.Offset(0, 1), rngCell.Offset(0, 2))
            lngMax = WorksheetFunction.Max(lngMax, rngCell.Offset(0, 1), rngCell.Offset(0, 2))
        End If
    Next rngCell

    Cells(lngPreviousRow, 4) = lngMin
    Cells(lngPreviousRow, 5) = lngMax

End Sub

Function lastRow(Optional strSheet As String, Optional column_to_check As Long = 1) As Long

    Dim shSheet As Worksheet

    If strSheet = vbNullString Then
        Set shSheet = ActiveSheet
    Else
        Set shSheet = Worksheets(strSheet)
    End If

    lastRow = shSheet.Cells(shSheet.Rows.Count, column_to_check).End(xlUp).Row

End Function
```

Points for improvement:

- `WorksheetFunction.Min` and `WorksheetFunction.Max` are repeating 3 times, it would be a good idea to build a separate function for them.
- simply use a dictionary, it will give a clearer solution. The dictionary should hold an array with two positions, one for the min and one for the max. But it is not as fun as the one above.

Comment: It works for most of them, however I am having trouble with the rows where there is only one year span between start and end date for that contract.  Example is the first row of data

Comment: @ACohen - if you delete the first row of your input data, e.g. `Sales Document`, `SLA` etc. would you still experience the problem?

Comment: I was referencing the `Row 2` sorry

Comment: @ACohen - I know. But try to delete the row and run it again. Thus row 2 would be row 1.

Comment: No, it actually just used the same number from the start date if the start and end date are within a year

Comment: I see where the issue is, your code is only grabbing the min and max of `column C` , ot the Min of C and the max of D

Answer (score 0):

Vityata has beaten me to it, but I started this so might as well post it.

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Range, r1 As Range, a, b

With Worksheets("Raw")
    Set r1 = .Range("A2", .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

With r1.Columns(1)
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
    For Each r In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        a = Evaluate("MIN(IF(" & .Address & "=" & r & ",IF(" & r1.Columns(3).Address & "<>""""," & r1.Columns(3).Address & ")))")
        b = Evaluate("MAX(IF(" & .Address & "=" & r & "," & r1.Columns(4).Address & "))")
        r.Offset(, 4) = b - a
    Next r
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).ClearContents
End With

End Sub
```